# Comparing two strings using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the following command, used in a C# WinForms app that uses OleDb to connect to a Access 2010 database:

```
oc_payslips = new OleDbCommand("SELECT <fields> FROM Payslips WHERE LicenseID = \"" + IDs[cb_Employees.SelectedIndex] + "\" AND DateOfPayment >= \"" + startDate + "\" AND DateOfPayment <= \"" + endDate + "\"", DB_Connection.con);
```

This doesn't work. My best guess is that I cannot compare two strings like that using SQL.

The idea is to get the records that have a date between two dates, all of which have the "dd/MM/yyyy" format. The date is stored as a string in the database.

I couldn't find the answer to this on the internet, so here is my question:

**Is there a way to compare two strings using SQL and determine which is alphabetically first?**

P.S.: I know I can get all the dates first, compare them and then search for the IDs which have a correct date but my question is related to doing this in a single SQL query.

Comment: 'single quotes' instead of \"double quotes\" for sql string literals?

Comment: @MarkByers i don't think `01/01/2012` vs. `31/12/2011` will be sorted differently in different languages ;) but there's no way these strings can be sorted the right way, they need to be converted to a date or formatted as `yyyy/mm/dd` string first

Comment: @MarkByers, not the point, I am interested if there is a SQL command to compare two strings like you would compare two numbers [using <= / => / etc].

Comment: @deathApril, the double quotes work fine. I know I should use yyyy/MM/dd, was about to change that too, but thanks.

Comment: @VladSchnakovszki the string sorting should work fine for yyyyMMdd format (just to be sure - both strings need to be in the same format)

Comment: OK, didn't see that you are sorting only numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems

- You should used parametrized commands instead of using string concatenation.
- You are using double quotes instead of single quotes as string delimiters in SQL.
- You are comparing dates as strings. If the table field if of type `Date/Time`, you would have to use a date litterals (if you persist in using string concatenation). If the dates are stored as strings formatted like "dd/MM/yyyy" the comparison will not work.
- Same thing with `LicenseID`. If it is a numeric type compare `LicenseID = 123` not `LicenseID = "123"`.

The three last problems automatically disappear, if you use parametrized queries.

See: [How to: Execute a Parameterized Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521.aspx) on MSDN.

---

```
oc_payslips = new OleDbCommand(
    @"SELECT <fields> FROM Payslips
      WHERE LicenseID = @lid AND
      DateOfPayment >= @start AND DateOfPayment <= @end", DB_Connection.con); 

oc_payslips.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lid", IDs[cb_Employees.SelectedIndex]);
oc_payslips.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", startDate);
oc_payslips.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", endDate);
...
```

---

It is a bad idea to store the dates as string in the database. If you want to compare dates stored as strings, it will only work if the strings are formatted as "yyyy/MM/dd" as Vlad Schnakovszki has pointed out in his comment. However, you could try to use

```
"... CDate(DateOfPayment) BETWEEN @start AND @end"
```

and make sure that you pass parameters of type `DateTime`.

Comment: I use \", which works the same as ' in Access, so that's not really a problem. I like it better cause I find it easier to difference between " and \". As I said before, I am aware that sorting the dates in that format would not work anyway, I was just interested in the method. LicenseID is also a string. Nevertheless, using parametrized queries looks a lot better, so I will try to use them from now on.

Comment: Your solution does seem to be correct. I will test it and mark it as an answer if it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-string-functions.htm#function_strcmp

afaik if it returns -1 than the first string would be before the second using english alphabet

Comment: Doing

    oc_payslips = new OleDbCommand("SELECT <fields> FROM Payslips WHERE LicenseID = \"" + IDs[cb_Employees.SelectedIndex] + "\" AND STRCMP(DateOfPayment, \"" + startDate + "\") = 1 AND STRCMP(DateOfPayment, \"" + endDate + "\") = -1", DB_Connection.con);

raises this exception: Undefined function 'STRCMP' in expression.

Did I use it incorrectly or might it be unavailable in OleDb?

Comment: it looks like a tutorial for (an unspecified) SQL standard, Access is not exactly the best example of implementing SQL standards..